# Is is possible to customize how comments are inserted via the Keyboard Shortcut?

Tags: python, pycharm

Is it possible to change the way PyCharm adds the hash `#` when using the keyboard shortcut to comment a line? (default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>)

I'd like the `#` to be at column 1 rather than at the indent level. Also, the cursor is moved down a line after the keyboard shortcut and I'd rather it stay on the same line.

Currently:

```
def foo():
    my_uncommented_line
    # commented_with_keyboard_shortcut
    var = "and now the cursor is at the start of this line"
```

What I'd like:

```
def foo():
    my_uncommented_line
#    commented_with_keyboard_shortcut
    var = "cursor stays on the previous line"
```

I'm currently searching around the JetBrains plugin repo for something that does this, but no luck thus far.

I know that this doesn't follow PEP8. I'd like to be able to make this change so that I can be consistent with the rest of the project:

```
Some other good reasons to ignore a particular guideline:

 2. To be consistent with surrounding code that also breaks [the guideline].
```

Comment: The keyboard shortcut to comment a like is `CTRL+/`. Are you sure you aren't talking about code reformatting (`CTRL+ALT+L`)? You also might want to take a look at the pep-8 guideline on [inline comments](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments) which is what you are demonstrating in your code example.

Comment: From PEP-8: `Block comments generally apply to some (or all) code that follows them, and are indented to the same level as that code. Each line of a block comment starts with a # and a single space (unless it is indented text inside the comment).`. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @IanAuld: I'm working on a project that uses this pattern rather than following PEP8 and we want to be consistent with the rest of the codebase.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Yes, I meant CTRL+/ (comment line). I've edited the post to have the correct shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The most you can do is alter the style:

[image]